# React native project to use heroku express url

Tags: react-native, express, heroku, url, publish

I have heroku backend express server project.I have react native project. I am trying to use heroku express url in my fetch in react native.. but I am getting network request failed.

I have two questions.
1.Why is that url not working in react native fetch, but opening in heroku.

2. Like react, can we put static files in build and try to serve that build in express app.use(express.static("client/build"));

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Also can anyone suggest me any other way to host my react native app for free and publish

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited my question. Hope you can understand my question now.  My problem is Fetching heroku url not working in react native. Thank you.